# JMeter: How do I create Load testing script when it accepts OTP on Mobile during registration?

Tags: web-services, mobile, jmeter, one-time-password

Scenarios is: During registration on Android App, OTP will be verified by App.

How do I create a script which allows to fetch OTP on mobile?

Comment: Can OTP be retrieve in another way as database or file or http call?

Answer (score 0):

If the OTP is being sent by email you can use [Mail Reader Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Mail_Reader_Sampler) which allows fetching email(s) for the specified account using [POP3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_Office_Protocol) or [IMAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Message_Access_Protocol) protocols.

See [How to Create a JMeter Script to Check Email During Registration AND Grab the Confirmation URL](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-create-jmeter-script-check-email-during-registration-and-grab-confirmation-url) article for example configuration.

Comment: Unfortunately, OTP is received on Mobile and verified on Mobile App itself.